# Spring Classes not found in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I am new to spring and i am trying to build a spring application using SpringSource Tool Suite. I installed STS from the .sh file available. I tried to do the following  :

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
```

But eclipse is not able to find these classes. How do I add this class to eclipse. If I need to import certain JAR's where do i find them?

Comment: I don't think it's a Spring issue, are you familiar with classpath?

Comment: You have to place Spring jars in your project's class path. HTH

Answer (score 0):

They need to be in the `CLASSPATH`.   That's where Spring looks for `.xml` context files when you use the `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` class.

Put JARs, including Spring, in the WEB-INF/lib directory.  If you put your .xml files in the WEB-INF/classes folder they'll be in the CLASSPATH by default.

Comment: where do i get the jars from?

Comment: where is WEB-INF/lib directory present?

Comment: Don't you know how to create a web app/WAR file?  If not, you need to go back to the beginning and learn some basics.

Answer (score 0):

here you go: http://www.springsource.org/download. First shot at google (`spring download`).

Answer (score 0):

Start with a Spring Template project.

`New Project/SpringSource Tool Suite/Spring Template Project/`

then select one, for example "spring MVC Project".

This projects are maven based, so they will download the needed/specified jars automaticaly.